# pass dynamic data to a view function MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am looping through a dataset in a razor view. I am new to MVC and Razor. ASP.net background.

```
    @foreach (System.Data.DataRow _row in Model.Rows)
{
        <tr>
            <td>@_row["FileNameShort"].ToString()</td>
            <td>@_row["FileSize"]</td>
            <td><a href="DocViewer.aspx?rowid=@_row["ID"].ToString()">View</a></td>
        </tr>
}
```

I need the filesize to be in MB, GB, KB all that jazz. Its in bytes. 
I've placed a Function on the view to format it. something I found somewhere else but it should work just fine.

```
@functions {

    List<string> suffixes = new List<string> { " B", " KB", " MB", " GB", " TB", " PB" };
    string Numeric2Bytes(int number)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < suffixes.Count; i++)
        {
            int temp = number / (int)Math.Pow(1024, i + 1);
            if (temp == 0)
                return (number / (int)Math.Pow(1024, i)) + suffixes[i];
        }
        return number.ToString();
    }

    string test(int number)
    {

        return number.ToString();
    }
}
```

If I just do this:

```
 <td>Numeric2Bytes(@_row["FileSize"])</td>
```

It complains that its an invalid argument even though its an INT in the dataset.

What is the best way to do what I need to do?

Comment: You should do all the processing you need for display before getting to the view.

Comment: @zimdanen agreed, but one could argue that the formatting of the size as GB, TB, KB, is a display issue and should be done in the view.

Answer (score 1):

You know it is `int`, but [`DataRow.Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/146h6tk5.aspx) property returns `object`. You need to cast it.

`<td>Numeric2Bytes((int)@_row["FileSize"])</td>`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<td>@Numeric2Bytes(Int32.Parse(_row["FileSize"]))</td>
```

or

```
<td>Numeric2Bytes(@Int32.Parse(_row["FileSize"]))</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Custom HTML Helpers, see the link:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs